Two laptops and a NAS
Two non-LAN'ed users with massive amounts of images and media we needed to share and secure; one Windows 11 the other a new Mac laptop. Purchased a 4-bay NAS from QNAP. My question to their support about connecting these components produced this response:

Your NAS model is equipped with two Ethernet interfaces. Therefore, you can connect each PC directly to one of the Ethernet interfaces of the NAS, as long as the static IP addresses are configured on both the PCs and the NAS interfaces. It's not strictly necessary to install a switch to interconnect all devices. The NAS software includes all the tools required to configure the storage system.

I asked in reply whether regularly connecting/disconnecting a laptop that interfaced directly through ethernet cable would cause problems, and whether a DHPC-assigned IP would be preferable in such a configuration -- and thus, some sort of "switch"? But no reply, alas.
I started configuration. I grabbed the NAS static IP address data during initialization but could not determine the "correct DNS server IP" (as directed by the NAS setup software). And that is the step where everything remains -- unconfigured, suspended, in limbo!
So, is some sort of switch a more rational way to connect these three components (perhaps a QNAP QSW-1105-5T?)? or is the static IP direction do-able and not an additional maintenance burden in the future?

You have no local network at all? You're not connecting these laptops to a WiFi network that you own or control? If not, you're stuck doing what they suggest, and it's probably the best option given a NAS is a "Network Attached Storage", as in, it is designed to use a network. A network gives several things including the DHCP server that would handle the IP addressing you otherwise must do manually. While it's possible to set up a LAN without an internet connection, that brings its own complexities.

@music2myear: Did you mean "A router gives several things" I guess?... Otherwise it doesn't make much sense. Two devices connected is a network; having a network has nothing to do with having DHCP (or having a router, for that matter) and having DHCP has nothing to do with having an internet connection. Now if QNAP's own software expects there to be an Internet connection during initial setup, that's a different issue, but the point remains.

Yes, in a sense. A collection of devices using APIPA is a network, but not in the sense OP was using and so I felt it OK to use the terms already in play to illustrate the contrast.

Yes, A switch is a more rational way, most definitely

As mentioned, a switch would make it easier.
If you are not using a switch, you can't necessarily use standard ethernet cables.  They may need to be crossover cables.
You can use DNS IP as 8.8.8.8, which is Google.  It has nothing to do with DHCP!
In theory it should work.  And there is no harm in connecting/disconnecting your laptop to the NAS box.  You could just use one connection and one cable (and time slice).

AFAIK, most NICs in the past 20 years no longer require crossover cables for direct client to client connections.

Anything gigabit or better will do autonegotiation by design

Typically a NAS or server vendors add two NIC's to a device to support link aggregation (802.3ad). Assuming you have a switch that also supports 802.3ad you can connect two wires from the NAS to the switch. Then when under heavy network load the NAS can use the full bandwidth of both wires to service client machines. Such a configuration also provides some protection against hardware failure - for example if one wire gets cut the NAS should continue to service request albeit with 1/2 the available capacity.

The configuration with two machines directly connected to the NAS, only makes sense in one specific scenario; When you don't have a 802.3ad capable switch and you have exactly two clients(machines) that have large amounts of files they need to transfer at the same time.
With only 1 client machine assuming the client and switch are capable of the full speed of the NAS port (1GB or 2.5GB) it doesn't matter if the switch is 802.3ad capable.
If two clients only intermittently use the NAS, it may be that they won't both need the full capacity at the same time / can wait a bit on occasion. So you can get away with a cheaper switch.
With more than 2 clients you will need a switch to plug them all in, it's (probably) worth investing in a 802.3ad capable switch.

I see that the switch you mention (QNAP QSW-1105-5T) is being sold (bundled) with QNAP dual NIC NAS's, however the switch doesn't appear to support 802.3ad. I think the reason for that is on this page:
https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/configuring-port-trunking-with-a-qnap-unmanaged-switch-and-a-qnap-nas
Specifically QNAP NAS's support balance-tlb and balance-alb which is a weaker form of load balancing than full 802.3ad. It's your call if you wanna go with that or pay (significantly) more for a full 802.3ad switch.
Note: If you do buy that switch now - you can always buy another switch later (if you need it) since you will likely find a use for a 5 port 2.5GB switch at some point...
TL;DR - A full 802.3ad switch will guarantee full bandwidth on the NAS.
QNAP's solution will probably be okay, its probably worth dropping the $100 for that switch to start with and if you really need to look for a more expensive switch do so later.
